# How to get methods inside vue, the methods is googlemap api?

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js

I have some google maps api that i've already craeted in javascript, but, for some time my collagues decided to use vue framework on the apps.

I tried to put my initMap of my googlemaps javascript inside vue methods and trye to call it on windows.initmap outside vue app, but it doesn't work,

here are my javascript code bellow

```
let base_url = '{{ envx('APP_BASE_URL') }}';
    let cdn = '{{ envx('CDN_ENDPOINT') }}';
    let endpoint = '{{ envx('API_ENDPOINT') }}';

    addEventListener('load', () => {
        const {
            createApp
        } = Vue;

        const initialState = () => {
            return {
                containerClass: 'container-grid',
                loading: false,
                properties: <?= json_encode($list_properti) ?>,
                filter: {
                    page: 1,
                    limit: 12,
                    keyword: '',
                    harga: '',
                    status_unit: '',
                    jenis: '',
                    id_propinsi: '',
                }
            }
        }

        const app = createApp({
            data() {
                return initialState()
            },
            methods: {
                checkData() {
                    console.log(this.properties.DATA);
                },
                getPropertiImage(imageUrl) {
                    const urlOnly = `{{ file_exists('${imageUrl}') }}`
                    if (urlOnly) return base_url + 'assets/img/no-data.png'

                    if (imageUrl === null) return base_url + 'assets/img/no-data.png'

                    const checkImage = imageUrl.split("")
                    const getFlag = [checkImage[0], checkImage[1]].join("")

                    if (getFlag !== '1|') return base_url + 'assets/img/no-data.png'

                    return imageUrl.replace('1|', cdn + '?key=')
                },
                setToBillions(item) {
                    let price = item;

                    let idrPrices = `{{ rupiah((float) '${price}') }}`;

                    let prices = idrPrices.split('.');
                    if (prices.length > 3) {
                        return [prices[0], prices[1]].join('.') + " Juta";
                    }

                    return idrPrices;
                },
                cicilan(val) {
                    let cicilan = (val / 1000000).toFixed(1);
                    if (cicilan < 1) {
                        return 'Rp.' + (cicilan * 1000).toLocaleString('id-ID') + 'rb/bln';
                    }
                    return 'Rp.' + cicilan.toLocaleString('id-ID') + 'jt/bln';
                },
                getAvatar(url) {

                    if (url) {
                        let explodeAva = url.split('|member');
                        if (explodeAva.length == 2) {
                            return cdn + '?key=member' + explodeAva[1];
                        }
                        return url;
                    }
                    return base_url + 'assets/img/avatar/1552FBA78C75D6FBA33F.png';
                },
                changePage(id) {
                    if (this.loading) {
                        return false;
                    }

                    document.getElementById('container-loading').scrollIntoView({
                        behavior: 'auto',
                        block: 'start',
                        inline: 'nearest'
                    });

                    this.filter.page = id;
                    this.updateContent()
                    this.initMap()
                },
                async initMap() {
                    const centerPosition = {
                        lat: -1.6160679698214473,
                        lng: 117.38277669882174
                    }

                    let map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("container-map"), {
                        center: centerPosition,
                        zoom: 5,
                    });

                    const areaProperties = []
                    for (const properti of this.properties.DATA) {
                        const exampleUrl = `{{ envx('CDN_ENDPOINT') }}?key=`;
                        let imageUrl = properti.GBR1;

                        imageUrl = imageUrl.replace('1|', exampleUrl);

                        const urlAvatar = ``
                        let imageMember = properti.AVATAR_MEMBER;
                        const imageAvatar = imageMember.replace('1|', imageMember);

                        const propertiAreas = {
                            position: new google.maps.LatLng(properti.LATITUDE, properti.LONGITUDE),
                            content: `   <template v-if="!loading" v-for="(properti, index) in properties.DATA">
                    <div class="card card-container card-shadow card--radius mb-2">
                        <div class="img-container">
                            <div class="img-top">
                                <div class="badge-report bg-colors-blue" v-html="properti.JENIS_PROPERTI"></div>
                            </div>
                            <img class="card-img-top img-card" v-bind:src="'' + getPropertiImage(properti.GBR1)"
                                alt="''+ properti.NAMA">
                        </div>
                        <div class="card--body m-4">
                            <small class="d-flex gap-2 align-items-center text-dim">
                                <img src="assets/img/shape/location.png" class="icon-location" height="12">
                                <div style="width: 100%; text-overflow: ellipsis;
                                overflow: hidden;
                                white-space: nowrap; "
                                    v-html="properti.ALAMAT"></div>
                            </small>
                            <h4 v-html="properti.NAMA"></h4>
                            <small class="text-dim">Mulai dari</small>
                            <h3 v-html="'Rp. '+ setToBillions(properti.HARGA)"></h3>
                            <small class="text-dim d-block">Cicilan dari <b class="text-black"
                                    style="font-family: 'Futura'" v-html="cicilan(properti.CICILAN)"></b></small>
                            <small class="text-dim d-block">Suku Bunga <b class="text-black"
                                    style="font-family: 'Futura'" v-html="'Dari '+ properti.BUNGA + '%'"></b></small>
                            <small class="d-flex gap-2 align-items-center mt-2"
                                style="font-size: 12px; color: var(--c-blue); font-family: 'FuturaMD';">
                                <img src="'' + getAvatar(properti.AVATAR_MEMBER)" height="25" class="rounded-circle">
                                <div v-html="properti.NAMA_AGEN"></div>
                            </small>
                        </div>
                        <div class="card-label--foot bandingkan-button" role="button" @onclick="handleCompare()">
                            Bandingkan
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </template>
                `
                        }
                        areaProperties.push(propertiAreas)
                    }

                    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

                    const icon = {
                        url: 'data:image/svg+xml;charset=UTF-8,' + encodeURIComponent(
                            '<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 640 512"><!--! Font Awesome Pro 6.2.1 by @fontawesome - https://fontawesome.com License - https://fontawesome.com/license (Commercial License) Copyright 2022 Fonticons, Inc. --><path d="M36.8 192H603.2c20.3 0 36.8-16.5 36.8-36.8c0-7.3-2.2-14.4-6.2-20.4L558.2 21.4C549.3 8 534.4 0 518.3 0H121.7c-16 0-31 8-39.9 21.4L6.2 134.7c-4 6.1-6.2 13.2-6.2 20.4C0 175.5 16.5 192 36.8 192zM64 224V384v80c0 26.5 21.5 48 48 48H336c26.5 0 48-21.5 48-48V384 224H320V384H128V224H64zm448 0V480c0 17.7 14.3 32 32 32s32-14.3 32-32V224H512z"/></svg>'
                        ),
                        scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(20, 20)
                    }

                    let marker, i;

                    for (i = 0; i < areaProperties.length; i++) {
                        marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                            position: areaProperties[i].position,
                            icon: icon,
                            map: map,
                        });

                        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
                            return function() {
                                infowindow.setContent(areaProperties[i].content);
                                infowindow.open(map, marker);
                            }
                        })(marker, i));
                    }

                },
                // async updateContent() {
                async updateContent() {
                    this.loading = true;
                    this.containerClass = 'w-full'
                    const filterData = this.filter;
                    const filterStrings = []

                    const lastKey = Object.keys(filterData).pop();

                    for (const key in filterData) {

                        if (filterData[key] !== "" || filterData[key] !== null) {
                            filterStrings.push(key)
                            filterStrings.push('=')
                            filterStrings.push(filterData[key])
                            if (key !== lastKey) {
                                filterStrings.push('&')
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    //FIXME string zero values
                    const params = filterStrings.join('')

                    await $.ajax({
                        type: 'get',
                        dataType: 'json',
                        url: base_url + 'api/properti/list-properti?' + params,
                        success: res => {
                            this.properties = res;
                        }
                    })

                    this.loading = false;
                    this.containerClass = 'container-grid'
                }
            }
        }).mount('#app')

        window.initMap = app.initMap();
    })
```

And here is the error that i got

[image]

How could i solve this?

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't call `window.initMap = app.initMap();` after creating the Vue instance but rather in the [`mounted`](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/lifecycle.html) lifecycle hook:

```
mounted() {
  window.initMap = app.initMap();
}
```